# Installing mySQL for windows

Tags: mysql

I downloaded mySQl zip file from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ . I downloaded the 216 MB file given in the bottom of the page. I extracted the zip file. But I cannot figure out how to install mySQL for windows. There is no setup.exe file or an MSI installer. This is what I got after extracting the zip file :-  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBA2W.png

 Please tell me how to continue. P.S. that I have tagged java because I have to use mySQL for java. :P

Comment: Yes there is, you just downloaded the wrong thing. Look again. And you still tagged for the wrong reasons; this has nothing to do with Java. If you want to build a rocket ship using Java for the software, you still don't ask questions about building a rocket ship in a Java forum.

Comment: you´re on the wrong board. However : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/5.6.html

Comment: @Gimby , then please can you tell me which file to download?

Comment: ... the one that says installer.

Comment: @JannisAlexakis , do I have to download the 234.8 MB file?

Comment: @JannisAlexakis , I have a 64bit laptop. Will 34bit work in it?

Comment: The installer is 32 but it installs both 32 and 64bit binaries. It says so on the page. Relax and read a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the installer file from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/5.6.html

Here is the the MySQL documentation for Installing MySQL on Microsoft Windows Using a noinstall Zip Archive: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-install-archive.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an installer, why not download the installer package?

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/5.6.html